# Reliable root procedure for LG G6?

Tags: rooting

Recently acquired an LG G6, model number: LS993

Android version 7.0

Is there a reliable procedure to root this phone?

Comment: When it comes to modern LG phones, waiting for an official bootloader unlock is often almost the only way out...

Comment: @AndyYan I was googling bootloader unlocks in general and actually this article which was written today came up by chance about the US LG G6 http://www.gsmarena.com/bootloader_unlocking_now_officially_supported_for_us_lg_g6_variant_as_well-news-25921.php

Comment: That's not it. Back then LG only unlock European variants; since G5 or V20 they added support for the US "open" variant because of complaints, but that's kinda pointless since the majority are still locked in with big carriers who have their own customized variants (and *never* eligible for unlock).